# Where was Snow White’s father, the King, during the events of the Disney film?

Tags: disney-princess, snow-white

In the original story, Snow White’s biological mother, the Good Queen, died in childbirth, leading the King to marry the Evil Queen.

But where was the King **in the Disney adaptation**?

In *[The Complete Story of Walt Disney's Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs](https://archive.org/details/waltdisneyssnoww00grim)* (1987), it's said that the King was [poisoned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyUZQ.png) by the Evil Queen, but is that really canon?

Comment: What would constitute canon in this case? Would you accept an answer based on the centuries-old fairy tale rather than Disney?

Comment: @Invisible-Trihedron - It's tagged Disney.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_(Snow_White)#Disney

Comment: https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_First_King

Comment: He appears in the Little Golden Book version, but then disappears abruptly without trace; https://archive.org/details/snowwhitesevendw00walt

Comment: [Hunting and whoring?](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_I_Baratheon#Reign)

Comment: It seems the Disney standard to have at least 1 dead parent. Sleeping Beauty is exception